# i am trying to create an app that can connect with metamask using walletconnect/react-native-dapp but i get this problem

Tags: react-native, blockchain, ethereum, wallet-connect

i am trying to create an app that can connect with metamask using walletconnect/react-native-dapp but i get this problem.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone encountering this down the road... Here's the solution.

React native dependencies in node_modules sometimes use outdated syntax such as the error above "compile" when it should be "implementation" depending on your RN version. I'd use the npm package `patch-package` or stack overflow how to properly modify dependencies (node_modules) to persist once you install another package.

I ran into this same issue with the same "walletconnect" amoung other errors but finally got it running - keep debugging! You got this.